# How to get access to cross domain content?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, userscripts

Two webpages, `http://website.com/home.php` and another one is on my dropbox `http://dropbox.com/myId/public/myfile.html`.

I want to run a user script (which will be given out to other people) on `home.php` with some values, basically some 9-10 numbers. These values are already defined in the script. But they have to get updated on a regular interval, this is done by the user clicking a link or something. These updated values will be on `myfile.html`. I have full control over this file.

I have tried using `localStorage` in the script but that doesn't allow to share content over different domains. `iframe` also doesn't work due to cross domain. But is there a way that these values can be *released* by a `function()` on `need.html` when the `iframe` loads on `home.php`?

I'm pretty new to javascript, so I don't know everything.

Comment: Looks like you are smahsing up PHP and JavaScript. What's a "userscript" for you?

Comment: @wumm A `scriptname.user.js` file. Just plain javascript.

Comment: How are you loading it?

Comment: @Quentin, if you drag and drop the `script.user.js` on the Chrome extensions page, it will install as an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

I created a `script` element using the userscript in `home.php` which links to `need.js` instead of `need.html`.

`need.js` contains code to add the "values" to `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  Here is [more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: Does Dropbox have a JSONP API for file access?